# Deleted SQL Agent Job Sending Failed Notifications

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, database-mail

I have deleted the job and I don't see it in the object explorer nor in sysjobs, and yet it is sending out notifications when it 'fails'. I've done the following solution:

1. Restart MSSQLSERVER & Agent + restart machine
2. Clean up database mail & past logs

Side note:

1. There's only one SQL server instance
2. This email triggers when job fails under SQL Server Agent
   [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is that January 9th or September 1st in your screenshot of the job failure?

Comment: no. its DD/MM/YYYY

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. What were the notifications? Did you receive a mail? What were the contents of the mail? Was it from the defined database server or was it from a different SQL Server instance? (Test maybe?) Please hit [edit] and add as much details as possible. Don't forget to black out any information that may be sensitive. Thanks.

Comment: Hi. Thanks and here you go the complete details

Comment: I'm curios: How can you show us the job details showing the e-mail notification settings, **if the job has been deleted**? Or is this from a different job?

Comment: its a different job just to show how the email is being triggered from sql agent

Comment: Do you see this mail in this view on the same server? `SELECT * FROM sysmail_sentitems`

Comment: yes and my last email was sent on 31/8/2023